# Follow up question to find $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{k} \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k \cdot e^{\frac{x}{3}} dx$ .

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, approximation

I need to find

> $$I=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\sum _{n=0}^kn!\ ^kC_n \left(\frac{3}{k}\right)^{n}-\dfrac{3^kk!e^{\tfrac k3}}{k^k} \right).$$

This was because I got stuck during an attempt to solve [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4502557/find-the-value-of-l-lim-limits-k-to-infty-int-0k-left1-fracx) by methods accessible to a high-schooler. This is basically the error in the approximation of the right hand term by the sum, by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376329/identity-of-binomial-series-with-factorial-sum-k-0p-binompk-cdot). Any help is appreciated!

Answer is supposed to be

> $$\dfrac 12$$

**P.S. :** If you want to see “my effort” then see my answer to the linked post. :)

Comment: And this series represents...

Comment: What do you mean…pls pls elaborate…not an AGP, not a GP, not(?) a Riemann sum…

Comment: I'm just asking what that limit is supposed to mean. Yes, you linked your post, but there really isn't much context

Comment: The series represents one-third of the limit of integral $\lim \limits_{k \to \infty} \int_{0}^{k} \left(1-\frac{x}{k}\right)^k \cdot e^{\frac{x}{3}} dx$ . I hope you have seen my attempt. Unless I have made some crass mistake, this should be it…

Comment: @FShrike I don’t know what other context to add…

Comment: The answer you linked reduces the problem to finding $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k!}{(k/3)^k} \left(e^{k/3} - \sum_{n=0}^{k}{\frac{(k/3)^n}{n!}}\right)$$ It should be possible to adapt an answer from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160248/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-e-n-sum-limits-k-0n-fracnkk/), after which you'd be done by Stirling's approximation.